# Prolog project issue with GNU Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, gnu-prolog

I have an issue with this code that works in Swi Prolog but doesn't in GNU Prolog.

```ml
:- dynamic libro/3.
:- dynamic prestito/3.

trim_whitespace(Input, Output) :-
    atom_string(InputAtom, Input),
    string_codes(InputAtom, InputCodes),
    phrase(trimmed_string(OutputCodes), InputCodes),
    string_codes(OutputAtom, OutputCodes),
    atom_string(Output, OutputAtom).

trimmed_string([]) --> [].
trimmed_string([H|T]) --> whitespace, [H], trimmed_string(T).

whitespace --> [C], { code_type(C, space) }, !, whitespace.
whitespace --> [].

% Definizioni dei fatti
libro('Il Signore degli Anelli', 'J.R.R. Tolkien', 5).
libro('1984', 'George Orwell', 3).
libro('La strada', 'Cormac McCarthy', 2).

% Predicati per la ricerca dei libri per titolo o autore
cercaLibriPerTitolo(Titolo, Libri) :-
    findall((Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili), 
            libro(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili), Libri),
    Libri \= [].

cercaLibriPerAutore(Autore, Libri) :-
    trim_whitespace(Autore, AutoreTrimmed),
    downcase_atom(AutoreTrimmed, AutoreMinuscolo),
    debug(cerca_libri, 'Autore inserito: ~w', [AutoreMinuscolo]),
    findall((Titolo, AutoreDB, CopieDisponibili), (
        libro(Titolo, AutoreDB, CopieDisponibili),
        trim_whitespace(AutoreDB, AutoreDBTrimmed),
        downcase_atom(AutoreDBTrimmed, AutoreDBMinuscolo),
        sub_string(AutoreDBMinuscolo, _, _, _, AutoreMinuscolo)
    ), Libri),
    debug(cerca_libri, 'Libri trovati: ~w', [Libri]).

% Predicati per prendere in prestito un libro o restituire un libro
prendiInPrestito(Utente, Titolo, Autore) :-
    libro(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili),
    CopieDisponibili > 0,
    retract(libro(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili)),
    NuoveCopieDisponibili is CopieDisponibili - 1,
    assertz(libro(Titolo, Autore, NuoveCopieDisponibili)),
    (prestito(Utente, Titolo, VecchieCopiePrese) ->
        NuoveCopiePrese is VecchieCopiePrese + 1,
        retract(prestito(Utente, Titolo, VecchieCopiePrese)),
        assertz(prestito(Utente, Titolo, NuoveCopiePrese))
    ; assertz(prestito(Utente, Titolo, 1))).

restituisciLibro(Utente, Titolo, Autore) :-
    retract(prestito(Utente, Titolo, CopiePrese)),
    (
        CopiePrese > 1 ->
        NuoveCopiePrese is CopiePrese - 1,
        assertz(prestito(Utente, Titolo, NuoveCopiePrese))
    ;
        true
    ),
    libro(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili),
    NuoveCopieDisponibili is CopieDisponibili + 1,
    retract(libro(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili)),
    assertz(libro(Titolo, Autore, NuoveCopieDisponibili)).

% Predicato per controllare i prestiti di un utente
controllaPrestiti(Utente, Prestiti) :-
    findall((Titolo, Autore, CopiePrese), (
        prestito(Utente, Titolo, CopiePrese),
        libro(Titolo, Autore, _)
    ), Prestiti),
    Prestiti \= [].

% Predicato per l'interazione con l'utente
interazioneUtente :-
    write('Ciao! Inserisci il tuo nome utente: '),
    flush_output,
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Utente),
    menu(Utente).

menu(Utente) :-
    nl, write('Benvenuto, '), write(Utente), write('. Cosa desideri fare?'), nl,
    write('1. Cerca libri per titolo'), nl,
    write('2. Cerca libri per autore'), nl,
    write('3. Prendi in prestito un libro'), nl,
    write('4. Restituisci un libro'), nl,
    write('5. Controlla i prestiti'), nl,
    write('0. Esci'), nl,
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, SceltaCodes),
    atom_codes(SceltaAtom, SceltaCodes),
    atom_number(SceltaAtom, Scelta),
    eseguiScelta(Utente, Scelta).

eseguiScelta(Utente, 1) :-
    write('Inserisci il titolo del libro: '),
    flush_output,
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Titolo),
    atom_string(TitoloAtom, Titolo),
    cercaLibriPerTitolo(TitoloAtom, Libri),
    (Libri == [] ->
        write('Nessun libro trovato con questo titolo.'), nl
    ;
        stampaLibri(Libri)
    ),
    menu(Utente), !.

eseguiScelta(Utente, 2) :-
    write('Inserisci l\'autore del libro: '),
    flush_output,
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Autore),
    trim_whitespace(Autore, AutoreTrimmed),
    cercaLibriPerAutore(AutoreTrimmed, Libri),
    (Libri == [] ->
        write('Nessun libro trovato per questo autore.'), nl
    ;
        stampaLibri(Libri)
    ),
    menu(Utente), !.

eseguiScelta(Utente, 3) :-
    write('Inserisci il titolo del libro da prendere in prestito: '),
    flush_output(current_output),
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Titolo),
    atom_string(TitoloAtom, Titolo),
    write('Inserisci l\'autore del libro da prendere in prestito: '),
    flush_output(current_output),
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Autore),
    atom_string(AutoreAtom, Autore),
    prendiInPrestito(Utente, TitoloAtom, AutoreAtom),
    write('Libro preso in prestito con successo.'), nl,
    menu(Utente).

eseguiScelta(Utente, 4) :-
    write('Inserisci il titolo del libro da restituire: '),
    flush_output(current_output),
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Titolo),
    atom_string(TitoloAtom, Titolo),
    write('Inserisci l\'autore del libro da restituire: '),
    flush_output(current_output),
    read_line_to_string(user_input, Autore),
    atom_string(AutoreAtom, Autore),
    restituisciLibro(Utente, TitoloAtom, AutoreAtom),
    write('Libro restituito con successo.'), nl,
    menu(Utente).

eseguiScelta(Utente, 5) :-
    (controllaPrestiti(Utente, Prestiti) ->
        stampaPrestiti(Prestiti)
    ;
        write('Non hai alcun libro in prestito al momento.'), nl
    ),
    menu(Utente),
    !.

eseguiScelta(_, 0) :-
    write('Grazie per aver utilizzato il nostro servizio. Arrivederci!').

eseguiScelta(Utente, _) :-
    write('Scelta non valida. Riprova.'), nl,
    menu(Utente).

% Funzione stampaLibri
stampaLibri(Libri) :-
    (Libri == [] ->
        true
    ;
        stampaLibriDettagli(Libri)
    ).

stampaLibriDettagli([]).
stampaLibriDettagli([(Titolo, Autore, CopieDisponibili)|T]) :-
    write('Titolo: '), write(Titolo), nl,
    write('Autore: '), write(Autore), nl,
    write('Copie disponibili: '), write(CopieDisponibili), nl,
    stampaLibriDettagli(T).

stampaPrestiti(Prestiti) :-
    calcolaTotalePrestiti(Prestiti, 0, TotalePrestiti),
    write('Hai '), write(TotalePrestiti), write(' libro/i in prestito:'), nl,
    stampaPrestitiDettagli(Prestiti).

calcolaTotalePrestiti([], Totale, Totale).
calcolaTotalePrestiti([(_, _, CopiePrese)|T], Accumulatore, Totale) :-
    NuovoAccumulatore is Accumulatore + CopiePrese,
    calcolaTotalePrestiti(T, NuovoAccumulatore, Totale).

stampaPrestitiDettagli([(Titolo, Autore, CopiePrese)|T]) :-
    write('Titolo: '), write(Titolo), nl,
    write('Autore: '), write(Autore), nl,
    write('Copie prese in prestito: '), write(CopiePrese), nl,
    nl,
    stampaPrestitiDettagli(T).

:- initialization(interazioneUtente).
```

When I execute the project with SwiProlog it works, but with GNU Prolog:

```
GNU Prolog 1.4.5 (64 bits)
Compiled Jul 14 2018, 12:58:46 with cl
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2018 Daniel Diaz
compiling C:/Users/--/OneDrive/Desktop/progettobiblioteca.pl for byte code...
C:/Users/--/OneDrive/Desktop/progettobiblioteca.pl:1:12: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
C:/Users/--/OneDrive/Desktop/progettobiblioteca.pl:2:12: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
    2 error(s)
compilation failed
warning: command-line goal 'consult(`C:\\Users\\lallo\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\progettobiblioteca.pl`)' failed
| ?-
```

Comment: Predicate `dynamic/1` is not declared as operator in GNU-Prolog, so parentheses must be used in directives; for example, write `:- dynamic(libro/3).` instead of `:- dynamic libro/3.`. Also, I think the predicate `read_line_to_string/2` is SWI-Prolog specific.

Comment: Parenthesis solved the problem. And what is the similar gnu predicate of read_line_to_string/2?

Comment: Please, see http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html.

Answer (score 2):

String is not a type in ISO Prolog. A string constant can be used (surrounded with double quotes) but it is converted as list of character codes, a list of characters or an atom (depending on the value of the `double_quotes` Prolog flag). In SWI Prolog, a string is a native type with specific built-in predicates to handle it.

Here is a possible implementation of `read_line_to_chars/2` returning a list of characters (or the atom `end_of_file` when the stream is exhausted).

```
read_line_to_chars(Stream, Chars) :-
    get_char(Stream, Char),
    (   Char = end_of_file ->
        Chars = end_of_file
    ;
        read_line_to_chars1(Char, Stream, Chars1),
        Chars = Chars1
    ).


read_line_to_chars1(end_of_file, _, []) :-
    !.

read_line_to_chars1('\n', _, []) :-
    !.

read_line_to_chars1('\r', Stream, []) :-
    peek_char(Stream, '\n'), !,
    get_char(Stream, _).

read_line_to_chars1(Char, Stream, [Char|Chars]) :-
    get_char(Stream, Char1),
    read_line_to_chars1(Char1, Stream, Chars).
```

To handle both Unix and Windows end of line convention, the end of line is detected when `\n` or `\r\n` is read (i.e. `\r` is ignored only if followed by `\n`) or when EOF is reached.

It is easy to adapt the above code to provide a `read_line_to_codes/2` returning a list of character codes replacing:

- `char` by `code` (this includes `get_char/2` -> `get_code/2`, `peek_char/2` -> `peek_code/2`).
- `Char`by `Code`
- `end_of_file` (as first argument of `read_line_to_chars1/2`) by   `-1`.
- a character constant by its code: `'\n'` by `10` or `0'\n` and `'\r'` by `13` or `0'\r`.

It is then possible to define `read_line_to_string/2`, e.g.:

```
read_line_to_string(SIn, Chars) :-
    read_line_to_chars(SIn, Chars).
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to unify `Chars` with `end_of_file`? `Chars` is meant to be a list, nothing else.

Comment: I follow SWI-Prolog: at EOF, the atom `end_of_file` is returned (an empty list corresponds to an empty line).

Comment: Ah OK, following https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_line_to_string/2 - I suspect it could be made a bit neater by removing the `empty` vs `non-empty` arg (using more predicates, instead).

Comment: `read_line_to_chars1(end_of_file, _, empty, end_of_file)` should set Chars *after* the cut, to be *steadfast* - https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/why-steadfastness/3313

Comment: A possible type for these `Chars` that are sometimes `end_of_file` could be `in_chars`